# I'm trying to make a bot with pyautogui that shoots targets based on their pixel color but the cursor gets stuck once the bot finds that pixel

Tags: python, automation

I'm attempting to scan through screenshots and find a specific pixel color location where the bot must move the cursor to and then click it, however, it seems like as soon as the bot finds the pixel the cursor gets stuck in a loop where it keeps moving a very short distance up and down. The site I'm using for this bot is aimtrainer.io.

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con
import time


# defining a function that moves the mouse to a specific 'x, y' position and then performs a click
def win_click(x_axis, y_axis):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x_axis, y_axis))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.2)


target_rgb = (255, 87, 34)  # this is the color that the bot will look for
x_fourth = 1366 / 4
y_fourth = 768 / 4
scr_shot_size = ((x_fourth, 3 * x_fourth), (y_fourth, 3 * y_fourth))  # this is cutting the screen such that it's 1/4 of
# distance from the border on all its sides
last_pixel = None  # this is just a placeholder

while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    scr_shot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    # these 2 for loops will scan the cut screen with a pace of 5 pixels
    # such that for each 'x', it will look for its 'y's
    for x in range(int(scr_shot_size[0][0]), int(scr_shot_size[0][1]), 5):
        for y in range(int(scr_shot_size[1][0]), int(scr_shot_size[1][1]), 5):
            curr_pixel_rgb = scr_shot.getpixel((x, y))  # gets the pixel in the current 'x, y' coordinate
            if curr_pixel_rgb == target_rgb:
                # the below if statements tries to prevent the bot from clicking twice on the same position
                if (x, y) != last_pixel: 
                    win_click(x, y)
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            last_pixel = (x, y)  # stores the value of the current pixel that will later be compared with the value
            # of the current pixel
```

Comment: pyautogui has a click() function you don't need win_click

Comment: you could locate the target with this too:      
pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("screenshot.png")

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend, you add a **Keypress check inside the nested loop**, so you don't need to wait for the whole loop to terminate before you can exit.

The problem with the stuck moving cursor is that you **jump each 5 pixels**.

Let's imagine you have a **Rectangle** of the size **150x300px** with its **top left corner** positioned at **(100,100)** and with the **correct color**.

[image: Rectangle Target]

As you can see, your cursor would **repeatedly jump column by column** inside of the rectangle.
(I'm sorry for this awful drawing)

You can try to fix this by **checking the whole color area** and place the **cursor centered inside** of it once.

Let me know, if you need help with that!